# When is a matrix function not a primary matrix function?

Tags: matrices

In Horn and Johnson's Topics in Matrix Analysis. There is this definition:

Let $A\in M_n$. $A$ has Jordan canonical form $A=SJS^{-1}$.

If $f(t)$ is a scalar-valued function of a complex variable $t$ such that $f(\lambda)$ is defined for each eigenvalue, $\lambda$ of $A$. And $f(t)$ is $(k-1)$ times differentiable at each $\lambda$, where $k$ is the algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda$. Then

$f(A) = Sf(J)S^{-1}$

$f(J)$ is the direct sum of $f(J_\lambda)$ and $f(J_\lambda)$ has entries defined in terms of derivatives of $f(t)$ and evaluated at $\lambda$ for each Jordan block.

$f(A)$ is the primary matrix function associated with the stem function $f(t)$.

There is an exercise in the book where we are given an arbitrary matrix-valued function on matrices (conjugating the complex entries of a matrix, matrix transposition, conjugate-transposition, etc.) and we have to say whether it's a primary matrix function or not.  I'm not so clear on what it means from the definition though.

Is my understanding correct,  that an arbitrary matrix function is not a primary matrix function if it cannot be defined by way of a stem function?

Comment: I have the book. What pages?

Comment: p. 410 for the definition.  p.447 for the Exercise #42

Comment: Almost. I have Matrix Analysis

Comment: Topics in Matrix Analysis.  It's a different book.

Comment: yeah first edition of mine is 1985, topics is 1991. I am looking at online preview, sometimes they show the pages one wants to see..........not this time

Answer (score 0):

If $f:D\rightarrow M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is a primary function, then for every $A\in D$, $f(A)$ is a polynomial in $A$. Thus there is no primary function $f$ defined on a neighborhood of $I_2$ s.t. $(f(X))^2=X$ and $f(I_2)=diag(1,-1)$.

Comment: Are those two necessary conditions for being a primary matrix function? There's actually a list of necessary conditions in the book.  One of which is that $A$ must commute with $f(A)$.  But what I'm having trouble with is negating the actual definition.